# Odd function (probability density function) describing the measurable quantity of a quantum particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy

This question is in reference to *Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecue, Solids, Nuclei and particles* by Robert Eisberg and Robery Resnick.

The setup for an infinite square quantum well with the potential function $V\left(x\right)$ symmetrical about $x = 0$:

$$V(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & x \in \left(\frac{-a}{2}, \frac{+a}{2}\right) \\
      \infty & x<\frac{-a}{2}, x>\frac{a}{2}. \\
    \end{array}
\end{cases}
$$

Since the potential function is symmetrical, it follows that there exists definite parity - there exists odd and even energy eigenfunctions.

In this case, the origin of the x - axis is the symmetrical point about which the potential function $V\left(x\right)$ is symmetric.
The measurable quantities describing the motion of a particle in bound states of such a potential must also be symmetrical about the symmetrical point of the potential.
But since the measurable quantities describing the motion of this particle is described by the probability density function $P\left(x,t\right) = |\psi\left(x\right)|^{2}$, $P\left(x\right)$ must be even for both odd and even energy eigenfunction.

To see this (suffices to show that $P\left(-x\right) = P\left(x\right)$)

$P\left(-x\right) = \psi\left(-x\right)^{*}\psi\left(-x\right) =  \pm\psi\left(x\right)^{*}\pm\psi\left(x\right) = |\psi\left(x\right)|^{2} = p\left(x\right)$.

The author makes mention
`The above is not true for the wavefunction itself in the case of an odd parity eigenfunction`

This remark appears cryptic and off - hand. My hopeless guess is that the author is saying $P\left(-x\right) = -P\left(x\right)$ should the energy eigenfunction be odd parity but this contradicts the results above.
Could anyone assist me in understanding exactly what the author is remarking.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a difficult time understanding what you're asking here. If $\psi$ has definite parity (either even or odd) then $|\psi|^2$ is going to be even. From what I can tell, you seem to be asking why odd functions aren't even. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: A PDF can't be odd, as it's non-negative but sometimes nonzero.

Comment: @J.Murray I made a change to a typo and better the question posed.

Comment: If $\psi$ is odd, then $|\psi|^2$ is even, as you have shown. You then ask what that means, but I don't understand what kind of answer you're looking for. If I asked, "what does it mean that $(-3)^2 = +9$," what would you say?

Comment: @J.Murray

Please refer to OP. I hope this is clearer. The OP was created late last night, hence the sloppiness. I apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is making the point that if the potential is symmetric about $x=0$ then there exists an energy eigenbasis consisting of functions $\psi$ whose probability densities $|\psi|^2$ are also symmetric about zero, but $\psi$ *itself* may not be symmetric because it may be odd (i.e. it might be **anti**symmetric).

Comment: Thank you for this.